# Is there any design issues i need to follow while designing UI in android?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget

I'm using Relative layout for designing UI. Please give me guidelines to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey, You can use Layouts according to the requirement that will depends on your application.
If you want to display the UI in table format then use TableLayout
If you want to display that line by line than use LinearLayout

like that you have to select the layout

Note: You can use multiple Layouts in the single Xml file that is in LinearLayout you can use tablelayout if required

Answer (score 2):

You will find lots of tutorials here: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html.

[Relative Layout](https://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html)

Answer (score -2):

Hmm, I'd suggest looking at JQTouch ( http://sencha.com) which is aimed at web-kit browsers, including iPhone and Android. It has APIs to help you with layout and various transitions. Seems to work well in Dolphin although I have not tried it on the iPhone.